# Как передать значение между диалоговыми окнами?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Не могу передать значение между диалоговым окном и главным окном. 
При нажатии кнопки на главном окне появляется окно выбора двух значении, при выборе одного из значении нужно переименовать кнопку главного окна на выбранное значение, но не понимаю как это сделать.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import mainwindow
from dialog import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
 
 
global Dialog
 
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.add_functions()
 
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.admin_)
 
    def admin_(self):
        global Dialog
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        ui.listWidget.addItem("A")
        ui.listWidget.addItem("B")
        Dialog.show()
 
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**mainwindow.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(260, 96)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
 
 
 
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нажми"))
```

**dialog.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-60, 250, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
 
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # Вот здесь непонятно как законнектить нажатие кнопк
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
 
  
    def accept(self): # Как тут передать значение в главное окно?
       # ?.pushbutton.settext(self.listbox.currentitem.text()) как тут отравить значение в main?
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

**q1373934_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from q1373934_mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from q1373934_dialog_ui import Ui_Dialog
 
 
#global Dialog
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):             # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.parent = parent                            # +
        
        self.listWidget.addItem("A")
        self.listWidget.addItem("B")

# Вот здесь непонятно как законнектить нажатие кнопк
#        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) 
#        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)

        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.save_all_data)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def save_all_data(self):
        item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
        if item:
            text = item.text() 
            self.parent.pushButton.setText(f'{text}')
        self.close()

 
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.add_functions()
        
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)                                    # +++
 
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.admin_)
 
    def admin_(self):
#        global Dialog
        '''
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        ui.listWidget.addItem("A")
        ui.listWidget.addItem("B")
        Dialog.show()
        '''
        self.dialog.exec()                                            # +++
        
        
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**q1373934_mainwindow_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(260, 96)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
 
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
 
 
 
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нажми"))
```

**q1373934_dialog_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-60, 250, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
 
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
#        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) # Вот здесь непонятно как законнектить нажатие кнопк
#        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
 
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
 
  
#    def accept(self): # Как тут передать значение в главное окно?
#       # ?.pushbutton.settext(self.listbox.currentitem.text()) как тут отравить значение в main?
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Doston, sorry, я не дочитал ваш вопрос. Теперь дочитал, проверьте.

Comment: @Doston,  что не так?

Comment: @Doston, если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour